# Animate UIImageView with overlayed buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

The main menu screen I have for my iOS app has some Round Rect buttons on top of a UIImageView.  I've got it all loading properly from an XIB.  But I want to fade the image out and load a new image in behind the buttons.

If I point at the imageview, I can change it to a new image, but the buttons are 'underneath' the imageview so I can't touch the buttons anymore.

Is there a way to preserve the layer?

Answer (score 1):

So it's the layer and not the animation you have a problem with?

You can bring forward your view with:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

or you can make a view not userInteractionEnabled which means your click will pass through the layer

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with your imageView:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{imageView.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ imageView.alpha = 1.0; imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png" }];
```